# Ajax call with bootstrap context-menu in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, contextmenu

In my MVC 4 application I have been using context menu with bootstrap following [**this**](http://lab.jakiestfu.com/contextjs/) and I am able to load the context menus on right click.

In order to show the menus on right click I have been using this as explained in above link which is the default code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 context.init({ preventDoubleContext: false });
 context.attach('.mylinks', [
  {
    text: 'Details', href: '#', target: '_blank', action: function (e) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ContextJS Bootstrap CSS Download', this.pathname, this.innerHTML]);
  }
 }
});
```

Within my application I have been making ajax calls in order to display a popup as or load the partical views as:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName", id = model.Id.ToString() }, new AjaxOptions
    {
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      HttpMethod = "GET",
      LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
      UpdateTargetId = "id",
      OnSuccess = "Something",
    })
```

Now my problem is that on right click of context menu ,when the menu is clicked I need to use above shown ajax call there such that I can display a **popup** or load a partial view.

Here as they have used **href**, I tried with calling a controller method from there but it refreshes the entire page and opens in a new tab.I also tried with providing **ids** there but again I got errors in jquery js pages in console.

I also tried with calling a jquery function on **onclick**  where I can use such ajax calls but that didnt work too.All these ultimately result in showing errors in the js pages in the console.So, kind of got stuck over here.

**Requirement**: After right click , on click of the menus shown need to make ajax call in order to display the popups.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this..?Thanks in advance..